# FluentValdiation & Blazor (Server-side), как обнулить кастомные ошибки?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Доброго времени суток.
Использую Blazor Server Side, Blazored.FluentValidation, FluentValidation, MudBlazor.
Через HttpClient получаю ответ от API, где могут быть ошибки валидации, которые нужно отрисовать на клиенте снова, но, если установить их через **EditContext** (модель валидируется в форме, API возвращает имя свойства, которое не прошло валидацию), то потом эта ошибка остается висеть бесконечно до перезагрузки страницы.
Как можно это побороть без костылей?

```json
"validationErrors": [
    {
        "propertyName": "Password",
        "errors": [
            "Пароль должен содержать не менее 6 символов.",
            "Пароль должен содержать хотя бы один небуквенно-цифровой символ.",
            "Пароль должен состоять как минимум из одной цифры ('0'-'9').",
            "Пароль должен иметь по крайней мере одну прописную букву ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "UserName",
        "errors": [
            "Имя пользователя уже используется."
        ]
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "Email",
        "errors": [
            "Почта уже используется."
        ]
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "ConfirmPassword",
        "errors": [
            "Поле должно совпадать с полем 'Пароль'."
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: При изменении нужного поля яваскриптом очищайте ошибку с экрана, это нормальная история. А вообще все что можно, старайтесь валидировать на фронте до отпраки серверу. Это не отменяет серверную валидацию, но делает жизнь юзеру легче.

Comment: Валидирую по максимуму на фронте, но пароль валидируется только на сервере, уникальность почты и логина тоже, как сюда попала ошибка, что пароли не равны - не помню уже, такого не должно быть.